# How do you use the expression "among others"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I know that you can say the following:

> "Einstein, among others, thought the sun revolves around the earth".

Can you say,

> "Einstein went to school with Dirac and Heisenberg, among others from ten countries"?

Answer (score 1):

"Among others" does not fit in the sentence that the OP has cited.

The sentence may rather be written as follows:

> "Einstein went to school with Dirac and Heisenberg and others from ten countries."

Answer (score 0):

You could say: Among others, Einstein, Dirac, and Heisenberg attended school. But if you really must keep the part about the people from ten other countries attending along with them, drop the 'among others' altogether.